# How to put a timer to appear on the screen?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am developing a quiz in the visual studio with Windows Form but I have to put a timer with a countdown of 20s to appear on the screen and when it reaches 0 it takes to the last Form which is the "Game Over" how can I do that?

Comment: [This Link](https://foxlearn.com/articles/how-to-make-a-countdown-timer-in-csharp-299.html) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.
The samplist is you can add a timer(from Toolbox), set `interval=1000`, then enable a Tick function when the quiz started, count the seconds down, when the totalSeconds hits 0, display "Game Over".

```
    private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(totalSeconds > 0)
        {
            totalSeconds--;
            this.timeDisplay.Text = totalSeconds.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            this.timer1.Stop();
            this.timeDisplay.Text = "Game Over";
        }
    }
```